# Two actionbars on top of the activity in android

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android

Is there any way that I can add two action bar on the top of the activity like this in eBay application.

[image]

[image]

I have searched for but only got it extended at the bottom of the activity which I don't want.

Comment: What did *you* try so far?

Comment: The eBay application doesn't have two actions bars.  What I see is an Action bar with either a custom header or perhaps listview header.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I used android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to bring action bar at bottom of the activity.

Comment: @wyoskibum ListView header seems to be my answer. Thanks